# How to access another class using C#(in unity3d)?

Tags: c#, class, enums, unity-game-engine

This is my problem: I have a player class and SwipeDetector Class in c#, the SwipeDetector class helps to do recognized swipe touches vertically on the iPhone.

p.s. I'm using unity3d but this is a programming question oppose to gaming techniques :))

In my player class I'm trying to access the SwipeDetector and find out which is swipe it was (up, down).

player.cs:

```
if(SwipeDetetcor is up){
   print("up");
}
```

this is the SwipeDetector class, it looks scary but its not!!

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class SwipeDetector : MonoBehaviour {

        // Values to set:
        public float comfortZone = 70.0f;
        public float minSwipeDist = 14.0f;
        public float maxSwipeTime = 0.5f;

        private float startTime;
        private Vector2 startPos;
        private bool couldBeSwipe;

        public enum SwipeDirection {
            None,
            Up,
            Down
        }

        public SwipeDirection lastSwipe = SwipeDetector.SwipeDirection.None;
        public float lastSwipeTime;

        void  Update()
        {
            if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                Touch touch = Input.touches[0];

                switch (touch.phase)
                {
                    case TouchPhase.Began:
                        lastSwipe = SwipeDetector.SwipeDirection.None;
                                            lastSwipeTime = 0;
                        couldBeSwipe = true;
                        startPos = touch.position;
                        startTime = Time.time;
                        break;

                    case TouchPhase.Moved:
                        if (Mathf.Abs(touch.position.x - startPos.x) > comfortZone)
                        {
                            Debug.Log("Not a swipe. Swipe strayed " + (int)Mathf.Abs(touch.position.x - startPos.x) +
                                      "px which is " + (int)(Mathf.Abs(touch.position.x - startPos.x) - comfortZone) +
                                      "px outside the comfort zone.");
                            couldBeSwipe = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case TouchPhase.Ended:
                        if (couldBeSwipe)
                        {
                            float swipeTime = Time.time - startTime;
                            float swipeDist = (new Vector3(0, touch.position.y, 0) - new Vector3(0, startPos.y, 0)).magnitude;

                            if ((swipeTime < maxSwipeTime) && (swipeDist > minSwipeDist))
                            {
                                // It's a swiiiiiiiiiiiipe!
                                float swipeValue = Mathf.Sign(touch.position.y - startPos.y);

                                // If the swipe direction is positive, it was an upward swipe.
                                // If the swipe direction is negative, it was a downward swipe.
                                if (swipeValue > 0){
                                    lastSwipe = SwipeDetector.SwipeDirection.Up;
                                    print("UPUPUP");
                                }
                                else if (swipeValue < 0)
                                    lastSwipe = SwipeDetector.SwipeDirection.Down;

                                // Set the time the last swipe occured, useful for other scripts to check:
                                lastSwipeTime = Time.time;
                                Debug.Log("Found a swipe!  Direction: " + lastSwipe);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which GameObject have you assigned the SwipeDetector to?

Comment: an empty object @farooqaa and the player.cs to my characterController. :)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access your `SwipeDetector` from the player class, you simply can use a public variable.

```
// Player.cs
public SwipeDetector MySwipeDetector;

void Update() 
{
    if (MySwipeDetector.lastSwipe == SwipeDirection.Up) { .... }
}
```

If you don't want to set the public variable in unity, you can use a kind of singletone pattern.

```
// SwipeDetector.cs
private static SwipeDetector _Instance;

public static SwipeDetector Instance { get { return _Instance; } }

void Awake()
{
    if (_Instance!= null) throw new Exception(...);
    _Instance= this;
}
```

And use it this way:

```
// Player.cs
void Update()
{
    if (SwipeDetector.Instance.lastSwipe == SwipeDirection.Up) { .... }
}
```

Comment: thanks felix i don't i don't mind using the public varibale, but its saying that SwipeDirection deosn't exist in the current context :))

Comment: @MidnightCoder You need to put your enum outside your class or use SwipeDetector.SwipeDirection. Be careful here because you might get some name conflicts, so better put the enum outside.

Comment: Using a singleton causes problems if the gameObject that is trying to access it is created before the singleton. You will have edit the Script Order and make sure the SwipeDetector script is executed before  the scripts that uses it.

Comment: @farooqaaa The singletone instance will be set before any update occurs, so the instance cannot be null if any SwipeDetector exists. I've used them many times in unity.

Comment: thanks guys, i tried doing swipeDetector.lastSwipe == SwipeDetector.SwipeDirection.Up, which deosnt give me errors :)), but i don think this class is working, im testing it on unity remote and i dnt think its reconising touches :((

Comment: @MidnightCoder But we answered your question! ;-) If you have another question you just could open another question on stackoverflow.

Comment: You should check out:

[answers.unity3d.com](http://answers.unity3d.com) for Unity related questions.

Comment: People still land here .. you should maybe avoid to use the same name for the type and the variable to avoid confusion ;)

Comment: @derHugo But this is totally legal in C# :-)

Comment: @FelixK. I didn't say it was not legal I just had a case where someone didn't understand that `SwipeDetector.lastSwipe` uses the instance not the type ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add a public variable to your Player class.

```
// player.cs
public SwipeDetector swipeDetector;
```

You will now see the SwipeDetector variable in the editor when you click on the Player GameObject. Assign that empty gameObject that has SwipeDetector (in the Editor) to it. And now you have access to that class.

```
// you can now use it like this:
if(swipeDetector.lastSwipe == SwipeDetector.SwipeDirection.UP)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it deos make sense, i just did it and i got an error it saying that SwipeDirection deosnt exist in the current context.

Comment: Use SwipeDetector.SwipeDirection or put the " public enum SwipeDirection { None......" code outside of the class.