# Can't figure out how to access an int from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know this question has been asked before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551575/how-to-access-a-variable-from-another-script-in-another-gameobject-through-getco) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457194/dont-know-how-to-get-enemys-health/26457999#26457999).
But I still can't get variables from another script. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
*(I'm really new to programming in general so I might have missed something glaringly obvious)

I keep on getting the error: `The name 'points' does not exist in the current context`

The slimespawner script is on the Canvas.

Sorry if the question is too simple.

here's the script I'm trying to access:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class slimespawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int points;
    public Text score;
    public float xx;
    public float yy;

    void Start()
    {
        points = 0;
        xx = Random.Range(-32f, 32f);
        yy = Random.Range(-18.5f, 18.5f);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        score.text = "Score: " + points.ToString();
    }
}
```

And here's the script that's trying to use the points variable.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class slimecontroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float movespeed = 0.1f;
    public slimespawner slisp;

    void Start()
    {
        slisp = GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<slimespawner>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        points += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried with `base.points`??

Comment: he means `slisp.points`. Note that if you reference this in the Inspector properly you don't need the whole `GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<slimespawner>();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access another class using C#(in unity3d)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822155/how-to-access-another-class-using-cin-unity3d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look as this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class slimecontroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float movespeed = 0.1f;
    public slimespawner slisp;

    void Start()
    {
        slisp = GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<slimespawner>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        slisp.points += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you reference this in the Inspector properly (since it is pubic anyway) you don't need the whole `GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<slimespawner>();`

Answer (score 1):

Access the property with `slisp.points += 1;`